# How unsafe can it be to read ot to use a linter of an untrusted piece of code?

Tags: python, security, sandbox, linter

Imagine you gave a Python exam to a large group of 500 students (or C, or Java, or other language, possibly anything).
You want to check the result of each code that your students submitted.

Of course, you won't have time to manually **read** all of them, and you can't execute the files because you can't trust your students!
It's most likely that at least one student has written a very evil program that will read your entire home folder, steal it by sending it over the network to his private server, then will delete and burn your laptop to ashes.

I want to know what is safe and what is not safe when dealing with such cases.

- I assume (and I really hope) that there is no risk in *opening* such an evil program `evil.py` in a basic text editor, like GNU Nano or Gedit. Same for any basic command line program like `file evil.py` etc.
- I hope there is no risk in *opening* it in a "smart" editor that performs clever "intellisense-like" code exploration (I'm thinking of VSCode, but Emacs and Vim and many other IDEs do the same)... but maybe I'm wrong... **Can someone please confirm or explain?**
- But what about using command line linters, such as [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) for Python, or tools like [mega-linter](https://nvuillam.github.io/mega-linter/) for other languages... So here's my quesiton: **is there any risk in executing such linters on a very evil input file?**

For the thought experiment, I have to assume that the evil hacker student knows exactly what linters I'll use to evaluate her/his code, and could design the `evil.py` code to attack this linter!

I would also be very happy if the answer is not specific to reading/linting Python (and possibly, safely executing the code from a local sandbox) but also to compiled language such as Java, C or OCaml.

Comment: Could you use a virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks @importhuh, so yes indeed using a virtual machine was my first idea. I also discovered [Camisole](https://camisole.prologin.org/), and actually I already started to experiment with both. My question here would be for solutions without virtual machine, so the scripts work (in a sandbox) directly from the command line. (this is part of a larger discussion https://github.com/Naereen/Peut-on-coder-avec-OCaml-Python-et-C-par-SMS/issues/2)

Comment: Also, using a virtual machine does not answer the question "How unsafe can it be to read or to use a linter of an untrusted piece of code?", it eludes it.

Comment: I realize that, which it why I gave it as a comment and not an answer. Camisole looks pretty cool. Also: Perhaps Camisole could be modified to run the linter within the virtualized system, then print the output as part of the json?

Comment: Oh that would be a smart way to go. I think the Camisole project is well written, and it shouldn't be too hard to add some basic linter and static analysis (or even dynamic benchmarks tools) to be ran when executing a file through the Camisole API. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

- if you are not sure, use linux and set all files as not executable :)
- vscode is not excel... a "hack" i could imagine would be to open a project with a recommended extension (in .vscode folder) , and that vscode extension would contain whatever could make your computer a bitcoin miner  But except that it should be ok
- Mega-Linter runs within a docker image, and it just read files, not runs them, so I think it's pretty safe :)

Bonus: wouldn't it be fun to run Mega-Linter with just the copy-paste detector on the parent folder of all your projects , to check who copied what to who ?